# Socket.io authentication situation

Tags: javascript, sockets, cookies, express, socket.io

I am using Socket.io with Express 4.

Socket.io has some middleware that allows you to authenticate a socket request before a connection event is registered.

The problem I am having is that socket.request.cookies is not defined. So the error that I register is that "no cookie transmitted", as you can see below.

the new middleware for this looks like this:

```
       io.use(function (socket, next) {
                var handshakeData = socket.request;
                //var handshakeData = socket.handshake || socket.request;

                if (handshakeData.headers.cookie && handshakeData.cookie) {

                    handshakeData.cookie = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);

                    handshakeData.sessionID = cookie.parse(handshakeData.cookie['express.sid'], 'foo'); //pass session secret at end

                    if (handshakeData.cookie['express.sid'] == handshakeData.sessionID) {
                        return next(new Error('Cookie is invalid.'), false);
                    }

                } else {
                    return next(new Error('No cookie transmitted.'), false); //I am failing here
                }

                return next(null, true);

            });
```

like I said, the problem is that handshakeData.cookie = socket.handshake.cookie is undefined. I believe that this value needs to be defined in order for the authentication to work correctly. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: See http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace and https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-cookie

Comment: thanks I have that working, but for some reason the session id for socket.io is not matching the session id for Express HTTP

Comment: Are you seeing the same cookie values via socket.io as via a regular HTTP request.  Start by logging those.  Also why this: `if (handshakeData.headers.cookie && handshakeData.cookie) {`?  You appear to be requiring that the `cookie` property exists in two places.

Comment: thanks, you can forget about the code above. The only problem I have remaining is that the session ids don't match between express and socket.io. I can see the browser cookie in Chrome under resources/cookies. I assume Express and Socket.io both use that same cookie value so I don't see how the session ids wouldn't match.

Comment: Uhhh, the most likely reason the session doesn't match is if the cookie value is different.  That's why I suggested you actually log the cookie via both http and socket.io to verify they are the same before you go looking elsewhere.  At least, that's the next step I'd take.  If they are the same, then there's a problem with your sessions or how you're looking them up.

Comment: hmmm, I guess I would have to log the cookie value in the front-end? I thought the cookies would be generated by the front-end, why would they be different?

Comment: I'd suggest logging the cookie value in an HTTP request in Express.  This is all server-side and that's where your sessions are created presumably.  Best to keep looking in the back-end only.  What kind of code are you using for your sessions?

Comment: I am using express-session and MongoStore, nothing too fancy

Comment: there is only one cookie value in the browser...so what you are saying is that Express would write one value for the cookie only to be overwritten by socket.io?

Comment: Answer me this then.  If you have the same cookie in two places, why does it resolve to a different session.  Either you don't actually have the same cookie or your session store is messed up.  I suggested you rule out the first option because that's real simple to rule out with two `console.log()` statements.

Comment: well, the one hypothesis that I have was that it was getting the key from the cookie but not pulling the value from the session store, then it would be comparing key against value, something like that. however, I don't believe what I just said is actually the case, so yes I think you're prob right.

Comment: I will work on this tomorrow, I think it's better that I just post a new question if I continue having a problem with this. thanks for your consistent help on SO btw

Comment: I print the cookie in the browser with document.cookie, and it's the same before and after socket.io makes the connection with the server. what do you think?

Comment: Your server code is creating a session and setting a cookie to indicate the sessionID.  What you want to see is if the web server and the socket.io code are both seeing the exact same sessionID.  If so, then the problem is somewhere in your session lookup code (same sessionID results in different sessions).  If not, then the problem is somewhere in the code that deals with session cookies.  If the sessionID in the cookie is fine and your socket.io code has the right sessionID, then the problem must be in your server-side code that uses the sessionID and associates it with an actual session.

Comment: ok, I will investigate...I wonder if it's that big of a deal for the express session id to be the same as the socket.io session id...for most cases does it matter?

Comment: It depends entirely upon what you're using the session for.  If you're authenticating the user using Express and trying to use that authenticated session in socket.io to know who the user is and to make sure the user is authenticated, then the two absolutely have to be the same.  If you're never using the session in Express and just want to identify a returning user in socket.io, then  you only care about the session you see in the socket.io connection.  But, the two should be the same if your code is working properly so it is something you should fix/understand.